# JQuery show / hide button dependents on number of textarea characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
  function countChar(val) {
    var len = val.value.length;
    if (len == 0 || len == null) {
      $('#sending').hide();
    } else if (len >= 500) {
      val.value = val.value.substring(0, 500);
    } else {
      $('#char_no').text(len + " / 500");
    }
  };
```

```html
<textarea id="txt" rows="10" cols="40" onkeyup="countChar(this)"></textarea>
<div id="char_no">0 / 500</div>
<input id="sending" type="submit" value="POST">
```

Above is my JavaScript and html, it can calculate how many characters are contained in textArea, but I want to hide the submit button if user didn't input anything, or user inputed something but erased them all. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to show or hide the button. Also it is recommended to add the event in JavaScript, instead of the markup.

```
function countChar() {
    if (this.value.length > 500) {
        this.value = this.value.substring(0, 500);
    }
    var len = this.value.length;
    $('#sending').toggle(!!len); // !! casts a boolean
    $('#char_no').text(len + " / 500");
};

$('#txt').on('input', countChar);
```

Note that `this` inside the function refers to the element.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/19sLaw7w/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- HTML -->
<textarea id = "myinput"></textarea>
<button style = "display: none" id = "mybutton">Submit</button>
```

Events are neat:

```
// Pure JS
var myinput = document.getElementById('myinput');
var mybutton = document.getElementById('mybutton');

myinput.onchange = function()
{
    var charcount = myinput.value.length;

    if(charcount == 0)
    {
        mybutton.style.display = 'none';
    }else{
        mybutton.style.display = 'inherit';
    }
}

// jQuery
$('#myinput').on('change', function(){
    var charcount = $(this).val().length;

    if(charcount == 0)
    {
        $('#mybutton').hide();
    }else{
        $('#mybutton').show();
    }
});
```